# How shall pre ANSI-C "0 pointers" be written in ANSI C?

Tags: pointers, c89, ansi-c

I am reading some old code and I am finding structures like this one:

```
Symbol *lookup(s)
    char *s;
{
    Symbol *sp;
    for(sp=symlist; sp!= (Symbol *)0; sp = sp->next)
        if(strcmp(sp->name, s) == 0)
            return sp;
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that the arguments can be specified in ANSI C in the following way:

```
Symbol *lookup(char *s) {
   ...
}
```

But I am wondering what to do with the 0 pointers:

```
(Symbol *) 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sp != (Symbol *)0` is still perfectly valid in ANSI/ISO C.  Any integer constant expression with the value 0 can be used as null pointer constant (C17 6.3.2.3 (3)), and can be cast to any pointer type, resulting in a null pointer of that type.  So this simply repeats the loop as long as `sp` is not a null pointer.

It might be a little more conventional to rewrite it as `sp != NULL`, but it's not necessary.  If you prefer to be terse, you can also simply write

```
for(sp=symlist; sp; sp = sp->next)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's just a way to specify typed null pointer, instead of the more common NULL from stdlib.h which has void* type, no way at all related with the way parameters specified in K&R C.